# Cannot create foreign key in MySQL Workbech

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, many-to-many, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to establish a many-to-many relationship. Here are the tables:

[image: Table 01 [user_needs]]

[image: Table 02 [age_ranges]]

Here's the relationship table:

[image: Relationaship table]

I can create a foreign key for **AgeRangeId** without any problem. But for **UserNeedId** id doesn't show any reference column to select, as you can see in the below picture.

[image: foreign key relationship]
[image: foreign key relationship]

I've no idea what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Column userneedid isn't ticked.

Comment: I cannot be ticked without selecting the reference column. And I cannot select the reference column for this key. @P.Salmon

Comment: Try to create an index on UserNeedId column first

Comment: Already created one. No luck. @PeterHe

Comment: It might be a bug in workbench. Just use SQL command to create the FK:  ALTER TABLE user_needs_age_ranges ADD CONSTRAINT FK_user_needs_age_ranges_user_needs FOREIGN KEY (UserNeedId) 
        REFERENCES user_needs(Id) ;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the UI you can just use alter table statements:

```
alter table user_need_age_ranges add foreign key (AgeRangeId) references age_ranges(Id);
alter table user_need_age_ranges add foreign key (UserNeedId) references user_needs(Id);
```